# Find the Derivative in step by step?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have looked the similar questions but all the questions are hard one and I can't understand.

My question is find the derivative $\dfrac{4z+z^3-z^4} {z^2}$, $z \neq 0$. 
I got this answer: 
$\dfrac{4+3z^2-4z^3}{z^3}$ 
however answer is $\dfrac{-2z^3+z^2-4}{z^2}$, 
looks easy; however, I can't get the answer.
 Can you please explain it in step by step? I appreciate it.
thanks alot.

Comment: Have you learned the quotient rule for derivatives?  The derivative of $\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}$ is?

Comment: no! I havn't learn yet.

Comment: Ah.  No worries, I think anon's answer should get you there without it.

Comment: Maybe you should first compute the derivative of $z^n$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It helps in this case to divide through for a simpler expression:

$$\frac{4z+z^3-z^4}{z^2}=4z^{-1}+z-z^2.$$

Now to differentiate:

$$4(-1)z^{-2}+(1)z^0-(2)z^{1}=-4z^{-2}+1-2z.$$

If you want to put this over a denominator again:

$$\frac{z^2(-4z^{-2}+1-2z)}{z^2}=\frac{-4+z^2-2z^3}{z^2}.$$